# Tricky Pandas Task - Reversely check other column based on True/False

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with 2 columns that basically looks like this. If i have true in B I want to have the last non-nan value of A in C. Is that even possible?

```
Actual table: 

   A   B  
0 754  False  
1 None False  
2 None False
3 None False
4 None True
5 999  False
6 None False
7 None True
8 None False
9 875  False

Wanted table: 

   A   B     C
0 754  False 754 
1 None False NaN
2 None False NaN
3 None False NaN
4 None True  NaN
5 999  False 999
6 None False NaN
7 None True  NaN
8 None False NaN
9 875  False NaN
```

Comment: The wanted table does not seem to correspond to what you describe in the text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Im unclear as to exactly what you want but what you describe in the text can be achieved by

```
enter code heredf.loc[df.B, 'C'] = df.loc[df.B].index
for n in df.C:
    if not math.isnan(n):
        cap = df.C[df.C == n].index[0]
        df.loc[cap, 'C'] =  df.A[df.A[:cap].last_valid_index()]
```

output:

```
       A      B      C
0  754.0  False    NaN
1    NaN  False    NaN
2    NaN  False    NaN
3    NaN  False    NaN
4    NaN   True  754.0
5  999.0  False    NaN
6    NaN  False    NaN
7    NaN   True  999.0
8    NaN  False    NaN
9  875.0  False    NaN
```